# Model Drift and Data Drift in azureml using python sdk v2

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, model-management

I'm writing to you to ask for your assistance in finding information on how to perform model drift and data drift in Azure ML using Python SDK version 2. I've searched through multiple YouTube videos, articles, and documentation from Azure but couldn't be able to locate any materials or resources that matched our needs. I am aware that my query is unrelated to programming or any other technical matter, but I need some assistance.

I have tried to implement data drift using python sdk v1 but it is not our requirement in the future it will gonna replaced and no one will use it

Answer (score 0):

Today AzureML provides a legacy monitoring solution (data drift) for model deployment and there is no GA for DPv2 yet.

AzureML legacy data drift solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/how-to-monitor-datasets?tabs=python

Currently the data drift and model drift in private preview, We will compute feature-level drift by allowing users to select drift measures for each feature. We will set sensible thresholds for drift alerting, which users will be able to override. Features will appear in a table ranked by drift measure. For each feature, we will show a graphical representation of the overlapping normalized distributions of feature values in the baseline and test datasets, which will allow for easier debugging. Upon clicking a feature, we can provide further statistics comparing the baseline and test datasets to aid debugging. Drift alerting can be set or muted at the feature level, as well as on a global dataset level.